# Python: Delete random elements in every row

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do this quite often in my code so I wondered if there is a faster way to do it. I have a matrix defined as

```
m = 100
n = 10
M = np.random.rand(m,n)
```

Now I want to delete in every row a random element. I did the following:

```
idx2del = np.random.randint(0,n,m)
arr = np.arange(0,m)
M[arr,idx2del] = 0.0
```

Is there a faster / cleaner way to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with this one?

Comment: @NikhilWagh Nothing. But I wondered if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Your solution seems fine. I prefer using the variable names starting with `mask_` (in your case it would be `mask_delete`) instead of `idx2del`.

Comment: getting `0.0` from `np.random.rand` isn't that likely but it's still possible, you probably want to set deleted elements to `np.nan` to not overlap with any legit value. Depending on your specific task masked arrays could be useful too.